# can I reduce a long array initialization to a short initializer list in C?

Tags: c

I have some C99 code that looks like this:

```
struct foo {
    char* buf;
    size_t buf_sz;
};

struct foo list[3];
list[0].buf = "The first entry";
list[0].buf_sz = strlen(list[0].buf);
list[1].buf = "The second entry";
list[1].buf_sz = strlen(list[1].buf);
list[2].buf = "The third entry";
list[2].buf_sz = strlen(list[2].buf);
```

Is there a shorthand way of writing this in an initializer list? Is something like this safe?

```
struct foo list[] = {
    { "The first entry", strlen(list[0].buf) },
    { "The second entry", strlen(list[1].buf) },
    { "The third entry", strlen(list[2].buf) }
};
```

Comment: Why do you need the `buf_sz` element at all if it's just the length of the string that `buf` points to? Is it being accessed enough to justify avoiding computing it on demand? Normally if you're creating an array of static strings, you'd just use `char *string_list[]` (perhaps with `const`). But if you really feel you need to, then I just initialize the strings as you show in your second example, but use `NULL` for the `buf_sz` value (temporarily). Then write a `for` loop in the code: `for ( i = 0; i < size_of_list; i++ ) list[i].buf_sz = strlen(list[i].buf);`

Comment: the `foo` struct is part of the API I'm using. I only happen to be passing in a character string. I could be passing in any data of arbitrary length.

Comment: Use a   **for** loop

Comment: @PaulH then you could use the `for` loop I suggested. And I meant `0` not `NULL` in my comment since we're talking about a `size_t` type.

Comment: IMO, `buf_sz` should be the _size_ of the buffer needed: 1 more than the length.  **or** change field name to `bf_length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be:

```
struct foo {
    char* buf;
    size_t buf_sz;
};

...

struct foo list[] = {
    { "The first entry" },
    { "The second entry" },
    { "The third entry" }
};

...

for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]); i++ )
    list[i].buf_sz = strlen(list[i].buf); // number of chars in string
```

If you need to put in the number of actual bytes consumed by the string, then you'd need a `+1` on your `strlen`. I don't know what the API requires.

Comment: @PaulH: I disagree. It has the initialisation at two places and does not work for a `const` array. But admittedly I'm biased, too :-)

Comment: @PaulH thanks. Olaf and alk have the solutions that handle everything at compile time rather than having code do the loading of the string sizes. It's a trade. And as Olaf says: it does break the initialization of the data up into two different places, which is fine when using `...` but maybe not so much when this is spread across a module.

Comment: @olaf. It's a tough call between yours and this. I did +1 yours.

Comment: @PaulH: Belive me or not, but I commented not for acceptance. :-)

Answer (score 5):

How about this one:

```
#define S(str)  { str, sizeof(str) - 1 }
struct foo list[] = {
    S("The first entry"),
    ...
};
#undef S
```

I `#undef`ed the macro right after the initialiser. Such short names should be used in a compact&short piece of code only. If you want to use it elsewhere, use a self-explanatory name (it should include the name of the `struct` type) and remove the `#undef`.

Note this only works with a string literal. But it works at file-level and does not introduce any run-time overhead. Thus it also works for `const struct list[]`, i.e. a constant array.

Be cautious about the `sizeof(str) - 1`. This is the same as `strlen` yields, but the allocated memory is actually `sizeof(str)`.

Comment: @alk:; Thanks. I added a more detailed explanation why I `#undef` actually. Hopefully a reader will keep that in mind for other applications.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
#define STR1 "The first entry"

struct foo list[] = {
  {STR1, sizeof STR1},
  ...
```

Please note that the size is set to `strlen(STR1) + 1`, due to the "string"'s `0`-terminator. To adjust this do

```
struct foo list[] = {
  {STR1, sizeof STR1 - 1},
  ...
```

Comment: Is putting the string in a `#define` treated differently than putting it directly in the code as in the second half of my question?

Comment: @PaulH Yes, because the size can be determined at compile time.

Comment: @PaulH: No. But I tried to follow the DRY-principal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself However, please note, that it is not possible to use `strlen()` as an initialiser requires a compile time value. Anyways for `#define STR1 "foo"`  this `{STR1, sizeof STR1},` is equivalent to `{"foo", sizeof "foo"}`.

Comment: Not the DVer, but your code contains a lot of redundancy.

Comment: @Olaf: You just got my upvote for your lovely macro soup. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use your second definition for a static duration `foo` array, because initializer lists for static duration objects are required to be constant. Draft n1256 for C99 states in 6.7.8 Initialization §4

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Even for automatic (block scope) `foo` arrays it is unspecified by the standard whether your second syntax is valid or undefined behaviour. Item §23 of same paragraph says

> 23 The order in which any side effects occur among the initialization list expressions is
>   unspecified.133)

and note 133 precises:

> In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization

That means that if would be acceptable for a compiler implementation to initialize the `buf_sz` members before the `buf` members which would lead to UB (even if it gives correct result without any warning on my old MSVC2008).

For that reasons my advice is to initialize only the `buf` members, and then use a loop to set the `buf_sz` members that require the structs to be already initialized - as a side effect, if can be used the same for static or dynamic storage duration:

```
struct foo list[] = {
    { "The first entry" },
    { "The second entry" },
    { "The third entry" }
};
```

and later in code:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]); i++) {
    foo[i].buf_sz = strlen(foo[i].buf);
}
```

Comment: Note: A string literal could be `"abc\0xyz"` and `strlen()` would report the same as for  `"abc"`.  Yet I suspect OP is not using such literals.

Comment: Thank you for quoting the relevant parts of the standard.

Comment: (Note: please cite the C standard. C99 is not valid standard since ca. 5 years now.) "Even for automatic (block scope) foo arrays it is unspecified" - Ehm ... no, it is not. An initialiser list for a `struct` (or `union`) always has to use constant-expressions. The only exception is using another object of a compatible type as initialiser. It is just a gcc extension which allows `auto struct` variable initialisers to have non-constant expressions. (btw. `auto` is not the same as "block scope").